# App crashes when starting a activity

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview app and wanted to updated app from inside when a certain text is present in the url.

I am calling these in shouldOverrideUrlLoading function of webview:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Update.class);
startActivity(intent);
return true;
```

And here is the Update.class

```
public class Update extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
        String fileName = "app-file.apk";
        destination += fileName;
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

        File file = new File(destination);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("http://example.com/app-file.apk")));
        request.setDestinationUri(uri);
        dm.enqueue(request);

        final String finalDestination = destination;
        final BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctxt, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(finalDestination));
                    Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    openFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    openFileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    openFileIntent.setData(contentUri);
                    startActivity(openFileIntent);
                    unregisterReceiver(this);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    install.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    startActivity(install);
                    unregisterReceiver(this);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

When I go to the certain url to start the activity, the app crashes. I would love to see any solution. Thanks!!

**I SOLVED IT, it was permission error.**

Comment: Any crash report ?

Comment: Use `adb logcat` to evaluate the stack trace.

Comment: My money is on `NullPointerException`. It's *always* a `NullPointerException` when somebody posts a problem in an `onCreate` method.

Comment: I have never tried adb but I just did now and it won't stop.

Comment: See thishttp://pastebin.com/raw/Zhgk66UD

Comment: I have updated the question with the log.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into ADB Logcat, which will help you to fix the issue. 
Otherwise, check into crash log or make sure that you have declared your Update Activity in manifest.xml

Comment: How do check the crash log? I am new to this so please guide me. Also, activity is declared in mainifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the new activity in your Android Manifest.xml

try changing this

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Update.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      return true;
```

to this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Update.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
 return true;
```

Let me know how that went.

Comment: Yes I have added the activity in the Mainifest.xml and result is the same. App still crashes after adding your code :(

Comment: check you app log and post the code from it...the app log is the little box that pops up at the bottom of the screen when you run your app

Comment: I am not running in the app the emulator. Installing it in a mobile so not sure how that box comes up. Can you tell??

Comment: Well leave your phone plugged in while you run the app, and may i ask if you are using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I am using android studio and I still don't understand what you mean with the plug thing. If you are asking about Logcat I can send you that.

Comment: yeah...please send your logcat

Comment: sorry about the delay was busy..i don't think this is what i'm looking for, at the bottom of you Android Studio you should see a tab that says "run".Do you see it?

Comment: I have updated the question with the log. Please confirm now